# Extract set of values from nested dictionaries/lists Python

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary `teacher` which contains nested lists of dictionaries. I'm trying to extract a `set` of names for all the colleagues and colleagues-of-colleagues of Joe Bloggs using a recursive function.

```
teacher = {'age': 27,
       'name': 'Joe Bloggs',
       'colleagues': [{'age': 34,
                 'name': 'Tim Smith',
                 'colleagues': [{'age': 39,
                           'name': 'Linda Smith',
                           'colleagues': [{'age': 41,
                                     'name': 'Belinda Barker',
                                     'colleagues': []}]},
                          {'age': 33,
                           'name': 'Kelly Brooker',
                           'colleagues': []},
                          {'age': 44,
                           'name': 'Duncan Turnbull',
                           'colleagues': []}]},
                 {'age': 29,
                  'name': 'Jenna French',
                  'colleagues': []}]}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{'Tim Smith', 'Linda Smith', 'Belinda Barker',
 'Kelly Brooker', 'Duncan Turnbull', 'Jenna French'}
```

Note the output does not need to be in any particular order since it is a `set`. As is often the case with recursive functions, it is difficult to 'make progress' without actually finding the solution. Thus far I have a recursive function which takes two parameters, but have no idea how to set up my function to generate the desired results:

```
def names(teacher, colleagues=None):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a set comprehension; the loop includes all names in the `colleagues` list plus their recursive colleague names:

```
def names(teacher):
    return {name for c in teacher['colleagues'] for name in {c['name']} | names(c)}
```

You could also express it as the union of the set of direct names and the recursive calls:

```
def names(teacher):
    direct = {c['name'] for c in teacher['colleagues']}
    return direct.union(*(names(c) for c in teacher['colleagues']))
```

Demo:

```
>>> def names(teacher):
...     return {name for c in teacher['colleagues'] for name in {c['name']} | names(c)}
... 
>>> names(teacher)
{'Tim Smith', 'Belinda Barker', 'Kelly Brooker', 'Duncan Turnbull', 'Jenna French', 'Linda Smith'}
>>> def names(teacher):
...     direct = {c['name'] for c in teacher['colleagues']}
...     return direct.union(*(names(c) for c in teacher['colleagues']))
... 
>>> names(teacher)
{'Tim Smith', 'Belinda Barker', 'Linda Smith', 'Kelly Brooker', 'Duncan Turnbull', 'Jenna French'}
```